# Можно ли отловить пароль подключения к базе SQLite?

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3, взлом

Есть программа. У нее есть база данных под управлением SQLite. База защищена паролем. Я вижу только 2 способа его узнать:

1. Брутфорс (но результатов его работы пока нет, да и не факт что будут ближайшие несколько лет :) )
2. Отловить его в момент подключения. Но как это сделать я не знаю. Пробовал через process explorer вытащить из процесса все стринги и подсунуть их в брутфорс. Результатов это не дало, но, возможно, это потому, что я упустил сам момент подключения к базе. Но как его поймать этот момент я не знаю.

Или, может, у вас есть другие идеи?

**UPD:**

Подключился к процессу отладчиком в составе Visual Studio. В тот момент, когда примерно должно начаться выполнение подключения к базе нажал на паузу. Вижу примерно следующее

```
740A4697  mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],ebx  
740A469A  mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],4  
740A46A1  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],ebx  
740A46A4  lea         eax,[ebp-1Ch]  
740A46A7  push        eax  
740A46A8  push        1  
740A46AA  push        740915C0h  
740A46AF  push        dword ptr ds:[740C57D4h]  
740A46B5  push        dword ptr ds:[740C57D0h]  
740A46BB  call        dword ptr ds:[740C6440h]  
740A46C1  cmp         eax,8  
740A46C4  je          740A46A4  
740A46C6  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-8]  
740A46C9  xor         ecx,ebp  
740A46CB  mov         eax,esi  
740A46CD  pop         ebx  
740A46CE  call        740BD40D  
740A46D3  leave  
740A46D4  ret         4  
740A46D7  int         3
```

Перемещаюсь по шагам. Ничего похожего на вызовы методов я тут не вижу. Подскажите что мне делать дальше.

**UPD2:**

Я не знаю на чем написано приложение, но оно подключает управляемые библиотеки (моно, unity и еще некоторые) а в папке plugins так же находятся библиотеки mono и библиотека sqlite3.dll. Пока не знаю ,что мне делать с этой информацией. Может, есть возможность подключиьтся именно к библиотеке sqlite3.dll и как то отслеживать обращение к ней?

**UPD3:**

Еще очень странная штука происходит. При потере фокуса окна загрузка с базы данных прекращается (ставится на паузу как бы). Возможно, это защита против отладки?

Answer (score 1):

Отладчиком это делается. Ставите точку останова на `sqlite3_key` и смотрите параметры вызова.

Если не поможет - ставьте точку останова на `sqlite3_prepare*` и ищите запросы 
PRAGMA key.

Comment: Извиняюсь за нубский вопрос, но как отладить скомпилированную программу? Чем нибудь типа IDA?

Comment: @iRumba IDA - наиболее "хакерский" из отладчиков. Но в данном случае подойдет *любой*.

Comment: Я еще немного вас помучаю. Добавил кое что к вопросу.